# Search random line

Tags: batch-file, random, cmd

I got 2 files bot.bat

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:botconfig
set botname=Unknow
set botcity=unknow
set botadress=unknow
set botage=unknow
for /f "delims=*" %%x in (botfeel.txt) do set botfeel=%%x
:askme
set /p how=
echo I feel %botfeel%
goto askme
```

and botfeel.txt

```
good
bad
sick
```

What i want is instead of showing just "i feel sick" it shows randomly one of the 3 words in botfeel.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your batch file look like this:

```
@echo off
:botconfig
set botname=Unknow
set botcity=unknow
set botadress=unknow
set botage=unknow
:askme
set /p how=
SET /a line=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768
if %line%==0 goto firstline
for /F "skip=%line% delims=" %%i in (botfeel.txt) do set "botfeel=%%i"&goto nextline
:nextline
echo I feel %botfeel%
goto askme
:firstline
set /p botfeel= <botfeel.txt
goto nextline
```

Comment: Try changing it to "skip=%line%

Comment: now instead of sick it give me bad,there is no way to make something like var1=bad var2=good on the .txt file?

Comment: i saved both .bat mine and yours,yours give "i feel bad" mine give "i feel sick" yours aways show the 2nd line on botfeel.txt mine aways show the last line on the .txt,no errors...

Comment: I found and fixed the problem, copy the code from my edit to my answer above